# How can i run tkinter commands after the GUI is open

Tags: python, tkinter

After the tkinter gui is open i want to change the name every x seconds referencing from an api in my code

```
ws.mainloop()
# -----------------------------------------
starttime = time.time()
while True:
    Value1 = data["session"]["gameType"]
    Value2 = data["session"]["mode"]
    Value3 = ' / '
    Value =  Value1 + Value3 + Value2
    ws.title(Value.lower())
    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

After the gui opens anything below it does not get ran until the program is closed.

Comment: `mainloop` will not exit until the application is closed, and should be the last thing in your `main`.  You must use `ws.after` to request a callback after a certain amount of time.  You must think "event driven", and not linear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.after()` to run a function after given delay:

```
after(ms, func=None, *args)
    Call function once after given time.
    
    'ms' specifies the time in milliseconds. 'func' gives the
    function which shall be called. Additional parameters
    are given as parameters to the function call.  Return
    identifier to cancel scheduling with after_cancel.
```

Below is an example:

```py
def update_title(starttime=time.time()):
    Value1 = data["session"]["gameType"]
    Value2 = data["session"]["mode"]
    Value3 = ' / '
    Value =  Value1 + Value3 + Value2
    ws.title(Value.lower())
    delay = 60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0)
    # schedule next function execution
    ws.after(int(delay*1000), update_title, starttime)

update_title() # start the periodic update task
ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you intend for `ws.after(...)` to call `update_title` instead of `update`?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes. It is a typo and thanks for your good catch.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply.
This didnt work for me, it does set the title to the proper reference from the api, but when it loops back and resets it its only setting the title again to what the api already knows, so is it possible to also loop fetching the api so it can update to the new reference the api is giving?

Comment: My answer is based on the provided code.  There is no code related to *api* that you said in your comment.

Comment: https://paste-bin.xyz/45165 view the full thing there, sorry about that

Comment: The issue mentioned in your comment is not related to this question, so it is better to create another question on that.